# How do I write a program that displays the values in this list of numbers sorted by their largest prime factor?

Tags: python, list, math, prime-factoring

## My list

```
numbers = [865, 1169, 1208, 1243, 329]
```

I want to sort this list in ascending order of largest prime factor

My input:

```
import math
maxPrime = -1
n=numbers   
# Print the number of 2s that divide n 
while n % 2 == 0: 
    maxPrime = 2
    n >>= 1     # equivalent to n /= 2 
          
    # n must be odd at this point,  
    # thus skip the even numbers and  
    # iterate only for odd integers 
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2): 
    while n % i == 0: 
        maxPrime = i 
        n = n / i
```

However, this is not printing n and I receive an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

My desired output:

```
Sorted by largest prime factor:
[290, 1243, 1208, 1169, 865]
```

Comment: Python arithmetical operators are not vectorized over lists. You would need to loop. Better yet, write a function which returns the largest prime factor of a given number, and use that to craft a `key` argument for the `sorted` function.

Comment: By the way, I don't think your question deserved a downvote. Python doesn't work the way you seem to hope it does (perhaps you are coming from R?) but your question was reasonably well written and contained the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you John, yes I have an R background.

Comment: The answer I gave is essentially the same as @John Coleman's idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is at the top, and the error message is quite straightforward:

```
numbers = [865, 1169, 1208, 1243, 329]
n=numbers    # n is now another reference to the list of numbers
while n % 2 == 0:
```

You cannot apply the modulus operator to a list.  I suspect that what you want here is

```
for n in numbers:
    while n% 2 == 0:
```

That should get you to the next error ... there are several in the program.  Fixing them for you is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this better with list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np
numbers = [865, 1169, 1208, 1243, 329]

#create function to be used in list comprehension
def largest_prime_factor(n):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
    return n

#use list comprehension to get the largest common factor
largest_fact=[largest_prime_factor(x) for x in numbers]

 #sort your numbers by the largest factor
answer=[x for _,x in sorted(zip(largest_fact,numbers))]
print (answer)

Out:
[329, 1243, 1208, 1169, 865]
```